# Network issues with ubuntu 16.04 on Lenovo Ideapad 510

Tags: wireless-networking, lenovo-laptop, ubuntu-16.04

After installing Ubuntu in my system, I am not able to connect to any wireless network! Sometimes it doesn't even show up the available networks. Can anyone recommend any solution?

Edits- for identifying hardware

**lspci -knn | grep Net -A3**

Output of the above command:

```
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8821AE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [10ec:8821] (rev ff)

Kernel driver in use: rtl8821ae
Kernel modules: rtl8821ae
```

Comment: We need to identify the hardware first. Please [edit] your question and add output of  `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3` terminal command. Ping me with @MichaelBay when done.

Comment: @MichaelBay I hope the update I made in question works for you

Comment: Try this answer first https://askubuntu.com/a/925866/692175 . Please [edit] again with the results if needed. If this doesn't change the behavior significantly then probably you also need an additional parameter to change the antenna selection to 1 or 2.

Comment: I found  the solution by installing the wifi driver,Thanks for your suggestions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, your network adapter have known issues with Ubuntu.

I suggest you to try these commands, from an AskUbuntu [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/983199):

```
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic build-essential git 
git clone http://github.com/lwfinger/rtlwifi_new.git
cd rtlwifi_new
make
sudo make install
```

This installs [git](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/git.html), clones a directory containing driver for your network adapter model and installs the driver.

Just in case the system doesn’t load the appropriate kernel module, you can execute the following command from within your `rtlwifi_new` directory:

```
sudo modprobe rtl8821ae
```

Comment: Yes it really worked !! Now I just want to see how this helps in the long run. Thanks a lot

Comment: my friend has the same wifi issue , but his kernel in use is << Network controller: Broadcom Corporation BCM43142 802.11b/g/n>>  .Is there any solution for solving his problem ?